# C++-style private access in Scala?

Tags: c++, scala

In C++, one can have (please forgive errors as I haven't done C++ in a while and corrections are appreciated):

```
class Super {
    private: virtual void g() = 0;
    public: void f() {
        g();
    }
};

class Sub: public Super {
    private: virtual void g() {
    }
};
```

such that `Sub` defines `g` but cannot call it directly.

Can the same thing be done in Scala?

Comment: `Sub` *can* call `g()`, since there is a `g()` defined in `Sub`. It can just not call `g()` on a reference/pointer to `Super`

Answer (score 2):

If you try it like this

```
abstract class Super {
  private def g()

  def f() {
    g()
  }
}
```

the compiler will give you this error messge:

> scala: abstract member may not have private modifier
>     private def g()

You have to declare `g()` at least `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing is

```
abstract class Super {
  protected[this] def g: Int
  def f { println(g) }
}
class Sub extends Super {
  protected[this] def g = 5
}
```

but this does not give `Super` any *more* access rights than `Sub`; it just prevents `Sub` from calling that method on other instances.

The exact same pattern is not possible in Scala.  (It would have to be a compiler fiction, as the JVM doesn't support it, but many of the access patterns are already compiler fictions.)